# How to use tuple as index in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns A, B, F and C. What I want to do is reassign values based on a tuple of columns, like this:

```
df[('A','B')=(0,3)] = 5
```

Which means, where A=0 and B=3, the values at the last column (C) should be 5.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot index by columns directly, you should either make A/B the index, or use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['A'].eq(0) & df['B'].eq(3), 'C'] = 5
```

Or, if you have multiple conditions in parallel, use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (df[['A', 'B']]
 .merge(pd.DataFrame([{'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}]), how='left')
 .combine_first(df)
 .astype(df.dtypes)
)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  F
0  0  1  1  1
1  0  3  5  2
2  1  1  3  3
3  1  3  4  4
```

Used input:

```
   A  B  F  C
0  0  1  1  1
1  0  3  2  2
2  1  1  3  3
3  1  3  4  4
```